# How to set fixed position to the button?

Tags: html, css

I created quite a simple search form - here it is:

[image: search form]

`onClick` it shows some more options:

[image: more options]

but the problem is that the second buttons goest to right after the bottom `div`, so i need somehow lock it in the current position and i don't know how.

[image: button place]

Actually it should be like this (bottom divs are "toggable" so it should show only one of it)

[image: final]

Here is [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/nonamez/PDjmB/2/) on *jsfiddle* (there not included view styles - only structure)

Comment: `div.advanced-search-values { position: fixed;}` will work?

Comment: Do you know position absolute, relative in todays markup and css. If yes use these.

Comment: why is this tagged `jQuery`? Is nothing but a css issue

Comment: I tried it before writing this post

Answer (score 0):

```
div.advanced-search-values { position: fixed;}
```

try this.

or use

```
div.advanced-search-values { position: absolute;}
```

Comment: tried - the page is big, so with scroll down it also scrolls.

Comment: @user1692333, then use position: absolute;

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your CSS, worked for me:

```
div.advanced-search-values{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: it jumps on the other styles after it.

Comment: What do you mean? Add the `position:absolute;` line to the `div.advanced-search-values` you already have.

Comment: Are you bothered that it's transparent, or that it doesn't push the page down? If you also add `background-color: white`, it'll lay over the top of the bottom elements.

Answer (score 0):

position absolute will work fine here

add the following line in your css:

```
.simple-search{
    float: left;
    position:relative;
}

div.advanced-search-values{
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 2px;
    position:absolute;
    top:26px;
    left:235px
}
```

here is the [jsfiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/PDjmB/13/)

Comment: As i said - i need fixed button https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14396564/screens/lol.png

Comment: "advanced-search-values" is in absolute position so we need to add padding dynamically while div is show...so I think its hard to achieve without js

Answer (score 0):

I just added position, & it works for me.

```
div.advanced-search-values {
display: none;
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
margin-top: 5px;
padding: 2px;
position: absolute; // or     position:fixed; (both works fine)
```

}

Comment: If its just about your buttons try:                                                                      .button
{
display:blocked;
    margin:2px;
}